# AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'linker_exe'

Tags: python, installation, airflow

I'm trying to install AirFlow, but keep getting an error. The line -
`pip install apache-airflow`

I installed Visual Studio with the proper packages, installed misaka, and updated both pip install version and setuptools.

The results -

```
Collecting apache-airflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/c9/db9c285b51a58c426433787205d86e91004662d99b1f5253295619bdb0e4/apache_airflow-1.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: future<0.17,>=0.16.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown<3.0,>=2.5.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.6.11)
Requirement already satisfied: alembic<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<2.11.0,>=2.10.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dill<0.3,>=0.2.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: flask<2.0,>=1.1.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-login<0.5,>=0.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.4.1)
Collecting dumb-init>=1.2.2 (from apache-airflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/32/817e967fa6c20d4568537016a2f27f00d9c6194778a41835e185e4feea0c/dumb-init-1.2.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy~=1.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy~=1.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: thrift>=0.9.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser<3.6.0,>=3.5.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (3.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: croniter<0.4,>=0.3.17 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.3.30)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor==1.1.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil<6.0.0,>=4.2.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (5.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.20.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs==1.0.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-daemon<2.2,>=2.1.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-admin==1.5.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-swagger==0.2.13 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.2.13)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property~=1.5 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments<3.0,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity==4.12.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-caching<1.4.0,>=1.3.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setproctitle<2,>=1.1.8 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate<0.9,>=0.7.5 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzlocal<2.0.0,>=1.4 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pendulum==1.4.4 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf<0.15,>=0.14.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: json-merge-patch==0.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.deprecation<5.0,>=4.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3,>=2.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas<1.0.0,>=0.17.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn<20.0,>=19.5.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (19.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: unicodecsv>=0.14.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorlog==4.0.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: iso8601>=0.1.12 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: text-unidecode==1.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<1,>=0.3.9 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8,>=6.7 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: apispec[yaml]>=1.1.1<2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Babel<1,>=0.11.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy<3,>=2.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (3.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<2.20,>=2.18.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (2.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-enum<2,>=1.4.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-sqlalchemy>=0.16.1<1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prison==0.1.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0.1<4 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyJWT>=1.7.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Mako in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from alembic<2.0,>=1.0->apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-editor>=0.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from alembic<2.0,>=1.0->apache-airflow) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from jinja2<2.11.0,>=2.10.1->apache-airflow) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask<2.0,>=1.1.0->apache-airflow) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask<2.0,>=1.1.0->apache-airflow) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from thrift>=0.9.2->apache-airflow) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->apache-airflow) (2018.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: ordereddict in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from funcsigs==1.0.0->apache-airflow) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lockfile>=0.10 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-daemon<2.2,>=2.1.1->apache-airflow) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-daemon<2.2,>=2.1.1->apache-airflow) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-daemon<2.2,>=2.1.1->apache-airflow) (41.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wtforms in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-admin==1.5.3->apache-airflow) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from flask-swagger==0.2.13->apache-airflow) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from tzlocal<2.0.0,>=1.4->apache-airflow) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pytzdata>=2018.3.0.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pendulum==1.4.4->apache-airflow) (2019.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas<1.0.0,>=0.17.1->apache-airflow) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=2.3 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Babel<1,>=0.11.1->flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (2.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-openid>=2.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5->flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1<4->flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1<4->flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python3-openid>=2.0->Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5->flask-appbuilder<2.0.0,>=1.12.5->apache-airflow) (0.6.0)
Installing collected packages: dumb-init, apache-airflow
  Running setup.py install for dumb-init ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xfdgqfty\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xfdgqfty\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4syt09xi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdgqfty\dumb-init\
    Complete output (33 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_cexe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdgqfty\dumb-init\setup.py", line 135, in <module>
        distclass=ExeDistribution,
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xfdgqfty\dumb-init\setup.py", line 95, in run
        cmd = compiler.linker_exe + [f.name, '-static', '-o', os.devnull]
    AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'linker_exe'
    supports -static...
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xfdgqfty\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xfdgqfty\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4syt09xi\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please go through this link - this may provide you some hint to resolve the issue. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/commit/f7503c4cd1c03fde215024e61db9e1a439f39997 I came across same issue and this is what I found and that would be root cause of this issue:
While installing "dumb-init" module, the version seem to be incompatible with windows.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. Seems like airflow 1.10.4 has a new dependency on "dumb-init" which doesn't work well on Windows.

Install Airflow 1.10.3 worked fine for me.

```
pip install 'apache-airflow[postgres]==1.10.3'
```

Comment: Thanks for this - been trying to get around this for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Robin Sun's answer i  used Airflow 1.10.3 then I got the setproctile error which i fixed by installing the C++ build tools  Windows 10 SDK

Answer (score 0):

Airflow had never been officially supported on Windows (only Linux and MacOS are supported as execution environment).

For sure you were not able to run it on Windows - but maybe there are other usages (like development environment that some parts of Airflow could work).

It would be great to find out what kind of usage on Windows you want and used so far so that we can support it in future versions of Airflow. If you have any suggestions/comments or would like to describe your usage of Airflow so that Airflow committers might work out on how to support Windows users in the future.

There is a JIRA issue opened for it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5375